# Listpicker with button in full mode in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, silverlight-toolkit

I put one button in listpicker full mode template. I want when this button is pressed. It Just invoke my defined event. Not act as normal tap on listpicker And closes the full mode of listpicker.

Please see screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

To include the button in the `listPicker full mode`, you have to define the `data template` as such. Go through the listPicker given [here](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/listpicker-for-wp7-in-depth)

```
        <DataTemplate x:Name="PickerFullModeItemTemplate"> 
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="16 21 0 20"> 
                <Button Click="event">
                    <Button.Content>
                         <StackPanel>
                              <Image Source="myImg.png"/>
                              <TextBlock Text="test"/>
                         </StackPanel>
                    </Button.Content>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel> 
        </DataTemplate>
```

For the behavior you require. Try and test by handling event function on `click event` in the button. I guess it should work. If not then you have to use `popUp` instead of listPicker. Or you would have to define your own `UserControl` in the worst case.